# Liquid: Why am I getting an Invalid Integer Error

Tags: liquid

I'm trying to do a loop:

```
<table class="table">

            {% assign bidderCount = site.bidders | size | divided_by: 4.0 %}
            {% for i in (1..bidderCount) %}
            <tr>
                <td>Item 1<td>
                <td>Item 1<td>
                <td>Item 1<td>
                <td>Item 1<td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

When I check bidderCount it outputs the correct number but when I plug that into the loop syntax I get an Invalid Integer Error. Is this not allowed in liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Liquid docs, `divided_by` returns the type of the divisor, which in your case is 4.0 -- a float. Floats are not valid integers.

Try this in your example, instead: dividing by an integer so the result is an integer:

```
{% assign bidderCount = site.bidders | size | divided_by: 4 %}
```